# .htaccess password not working

Tags: .htaccess, htpasswd, .htpasswd

I've been trying to use .htaccess to password protect a folder for a website. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not getting an error, but the password being set in the .htpasswd file is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I can only assume my issue is I'm getting the path wrong for my .htpasswd file.

I used php to find the path and got this:

/var/www/vhosts/[MYURL]/httpdocs/clients/[CLIENT]/trade/.htpasswd

so I used the following code in my .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/[MYURL]/httpdocs/clients/[CLIENT]/trade/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why my passwords aren't being accepted?

Comment: Are you using the right format in the .htpasswd file? Can you post an example of what you made with bogus credentials?

Comment: So is the server requesting a password but the configured password isn't accepted?

Comment: Yeah, pops up looking for password, but the password I input isn't accepted.

My .htpasswd text looks similar to this:
admin:admin

Comment: Could it be because I haven't encrypted it? I originally used an online generator to get a password, but that didn't seem to work on my localhost, so I changed it to the exact text.
Now that it's on a server I guess I could try a generated password again.
Will post update.

Comment: I think you want to look up the "htpasswd" command, which if you run it as "htpasswd -n <username>", it will output the line that you need to put in your .htpasswd file.

Comment: Problem solved! Needed to change to a generated encrypted password!

Comment: I managed to solve this.

The issue was because in my .htpasswd file I hadn't used an encrypted password and had just tried to use plain text.

Original not working .htpasswd

`code`admin:admin

Working .htpasswd

`code`admin:$apr1$.qqvOm22$uQmilaI66H88o5qiq/UbD1

(if you're looking for a password generator, I used: 
http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the htpasswd binary as I specified above which should be in the apache/bin directory